# Meaning of "to gird up one's loins" (King James English)

Tags: idiom-meaning

What is the meaning of [to] "gird up [one's] loins"?

Comment: I assume from the fact that you refer to this as "King James English" that you are quoting from the Bible.  If so, you could easily check the same verse is a modern Bible.

Answer (score 2):

The literal meaning is reasonably clear if you understand the verb *gird*.

> **gird**
>
> *transitive verb*
>
> 1a : to encircle or bind with a flexible band (such as a belt)
>   b : to make (something, such as clothing or a sword ) fast or secure (as with a cord or belt)
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gird

[image: How to Gird Your Loins]

> Back in the days of the ancient Near East, both men and women wore flowing tunics. Around the tunic, they’d wear a belt or girdle. While tunics were comfortable and breezy, the hem of the tunic would often get in the way when a man was fighting or performing hard labor. So when ancient Hebrew men had to battle the Philistines, the men would lift the hem of their tunic up and tuck it into their girdle or tie it in a knot to keep it off the ground. The effect basically created a pair of shorts that provided more freedom of movement.
>
> https://www.artofmanliness.com/articles/how-to-gird-up-your-loins-an-illustrated-guide/

Comment: So, basically the same thing as ***hiking up one’s skirts***, eh? :)

Comment: An entirely irresistible answer. :) Compared to some questions, this is not worthy of "vote to close" as the answer is so amusing.

Comment: So I'm suitably amused. :) That said, this feels like folk etymology. *Girding* literally refers to wearing a belt or girdle. 2 Samuel 20:18 (KJV) refers to "a girdle with a sword fastened upon his loins in the sheath thereof," suggesting only a girdle, and 1 Kings 20:32 has "So they girded sackcloth on their loins," suggesting only applying a sackcloth belt. Similarly 2 Kings 1:8 has "girt with a girdle of leather about his loins," and Job 12:18 has "girdeth their loins with a girdle." How do we know that all these extra steps are involved?

Comment: Whew, okay. "The Tosefta evidently refers to a beltlike structure used to collect loose clothing around the hips and chest, and thus to free the legs and arms for movement" (109-10 in ["She Binds Her Arms": Rereading Proverbs 31:17](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25610169)  ). I can accept the above as one way to gather clothing. :)

Comment: OED: the explanation is right: a. transitive. To surround, encircle (the waist, a person about the waist) with a belt or girdle, esp. for the purpose of confining the garments and allowing freer action to the body. Chiefly reflexive or passive; also, after Biblical phrase, to gird one's loins, to gird one's reins, etc. Also to gird up, to gird about. [the second meaning for the verb is very different. :)]